# Document root element "persistence", must match DOCTYPE root "null". for persistence.xml JPA

Tags: xml, hibernate, jpa, xsd, dtd

I am getting the following error

> Document root element "persistence", must match DOCTYPE root "null"

Below is the XML file causing it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

        <persistence-unit name="my-persistence">
            <description>Persistence Unit</description>
            <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
            <mapping-file>WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml</mapping-file>
            <!--<jar-file>packedEntity.jar</jar-file>-->
            <class>domain.Applicant</class>
            <class>testScrEntry</class>
            <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>

    </persistence>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
 o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext WARN: Exception encountered during 
 context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed 
 to parse configuration class [configuration.JpaConfiguration]; nested 
 exception is java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException:  
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "persistence", must     
 match DOCTYPE root "`null"
```

Naturally I googled the error and it tells me to add  which I did and it looked like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE persistence PUBLIC xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="my-pu">
        <description>Persistence Unit</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!--<mapping-file>application-context.xml</mapping-file>-->
        <!--<jar-file>packedEntity.jar</jar-file>-->
        <class>domain.Applicant</class>
        <class>applicant.testScrEntry</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

However the above also doesn't saying the file must be close by a `>`. It is referring to the red ~ line next to `</persistence>`.

`The public identifier must begin with either a single or double quote character.`

---------------------UPDATE 1------------------------------

I have tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE persistence PUBLIC
        "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
```

Error: :`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:The public identifier must begin with either a single or double quote character.`

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
```

ERROR: `Document root element "persistence", must match DOCTYPE root "null".`

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
```

Document root element "persistence", must match DOCTYPE root "null".

Comment: XML schema is wrong. Look at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/emf.html#Persistence_Unit

Comment: @NeilStockton I looked at it and it was not to get rid of the compiler complaining but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: @Mike3355 what was your issue? were you able to resolve it? do you still remember?

Answer (score 0):

Your second "XML" document is a mangled mess of XSD and DTD constructs with the end result being a document that is not XML at all -- not well-formed, let alone valid.

Your first XML document is valid against the XSD declared via `@schemaLocation`.   The error message is DTD based, not XSD based.  Parse it against the XSD hinted about in the `@schemaLocation`, and you'll be fine.

Comment: did you find the fix? the same problem is there for me as well and i'm getting exactly same errors as you got for each scenario.

Comment: @AbhishekMaheshwari: Post a new question with a [mcve] of your specific problem.  The MCVE of this question is a mess -- not something you can piggyback upon.  One hint:  Pick XSD ***or*** DTD; you nearly never need both.

Comment: @kjhughes: Thanks for the suggestion. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248124/document-root-element-persistence-must-match-doctype-root-null